# snmpd configuration to enable BRIDGE-MIB or Q-BRIDGE-MIB

Tags: linux, switch, vlan, snmp, bridge

All the Ethernet switches and access points on my network provide snmp access to the bridge learn table except for my linux-based bridge.

Does net-snmp support exporting the bridge forwarding database via snmp?  This is BRIDGE-MIB defined in RFC 1493 (or even better, Q-BRIDGE-MIB defined in RFC2674).  What snmpd configuration options are needed to make this work?  Do I need to build and deploy some of the optional agents?

Is there a better way to remotely gather the information displayed by `brctl showmacs br0` (specifically, the list of learned MAC addresses and the port number via which each is reachable)?

Comment: I really don't know how to do this and have been interesting in how to extend SNMPD for some time, just haven't put effort into it yet. This link seems promising, let me know how you make out. http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff: I've seen that link, but it seems only to describe how to use MIBs with the client tools to format output.  The server tools don't seem to use the MIB files at all (and that makes sense, since they need per-OID logic to supply the data, not just the formatting data provided from the MIB).

Comment: That makes sense to me, mibs are for making sense of output, not creating it. Keep us posted.

Answer (score 2):

I also found this man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmp-bridge-mib

It *might* be another implementation that might even work.

It seems OpenVSwitch does better in that aspect.

Comment: snmp-bridge-mib is provided with net-snmp, still strugling with how to start it properly tho

Answer (score 1):

I found one agent.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/q-bridge-mib/

It has to be compiled with [`scons`](http://www.scons.org/), "agentx master" mode has to be enabled in snmpd.conf, and then the `q-bridge-mib` executable can be launched.  It daemonizes itself and happily runs in the background supplying the dot1d subtree.

Then it works.... sort of.  The port column of the forwarding table is definitely not being populated correctly.  But it's still under development and source code is available, so maybe I can figure out what's going wrong.

I'd still be interested in a more mature implementation if anyone knows of one.